# How can I configure link aggregation/bonded LAN for my simple Ubuntu router build?

Tags: switch, router, lan, linux, ieee-802.1ax

I'm spinning out on this one...! Someone please help!

I followed this fab tutorial below to make my own Ubuntu based router:

[How to build a simple router Ubuntu Server 18.04](https://www.ascinc.com/blog/linux/how-to-build-a-simple-router-with-ubuntu-server-18-04-1-lts-bionic-beaver/#comment-23)

Which works great using only **two ports of the four ports available** on my hardware which is: 
 
- old lenovo desktop with an old [4 port HP Gigabit Adaptor NC364T](https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docLocale=en_US&docId=emr_na-c01735658) 
- interface 1 (WAN): DHCP conn to BT HomeHub router (192.168.1.?/24)
 
- interface 2 (LAN): static 10.1.0.1 with DHCP server setup over subnet 10.1.0.0/24
- interface 2 then connects to a new Cisco SG220-26 switch and hey presto I'm up with all my LAN devices!

However.... as I have some storage in the box as well and both switch/net card support link aggregation. I thought I could create a bond in netplan and increase the bandwidth (e.g. use 1 port for WAN, 3 other for LAN aggregated link to the switch) plus its a learning exercise right....?!

**I can't seem to get this to work..either as a bond or adding static/dhcp interfaces to my netplan yaml**

Here is the **working** netplan yaml for the **two port** version:

```
network:
ethernets:
    enp3s0f0:
        dhcp4: true
    enp3s0f1:
        addresses:
        - 10.1.0.1/24
        dhcp4: false
        nameservers:
            addresses:
            - 8.8.8.8
            - 8.8.4.4
            search: []
version: 2
```

And the **working** /etc/rc.local iptables configuration:

```
#!/bin/bash

# /etc/rc.local

# Default policy to drop all incoming packets.
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP

# Accept incoming packets from localhost and the LAN interface.
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i enp3s0f1 -j ACCEPT

# Accept incoming packets from the WAN if the router initiated the connection.
iptables -A INPUT -i enp3s0f0 -m conntrack \
--ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Forward LAN packets to the WAN.
iptables -A FORWARD -i enp3s0f1 -o enp3s0f0 -j ACCEPT

# Forward WAN packets to the LAN if the LAN initiated the connection.
iptables -A FORWARD -i enp3s0f0 -o enp3s0f1 -m conntrack \
--ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# NAT traffic going out the WAN interface.
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp3s0f0 -j MASQUERADE

# rc.local needs to exit with 0
exit 0
```

Using the [netplan example for a bonded router](https://netplan.io/examples) as a starting point, my **not working bonded netplan yaml** looks like:

```
network:
version: 2
ethernets:
    enp3s0f0:
        dhcp4: yes
    enp3s0f1:
        dhcp4: false
    enp4s0f0:
        dhcp4: false
        optional: true
    enp4s0f1:
        dhcp4: false
        optional: true
bonds:
  pigeon-lan:
    interfaces: [enp3s0f1, enp4s0f0, enp4s0f1]
    addresses: [10.1.0.1/24]
    nameservers:
      addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
      search: []
    parameters:
      mode: 802.3ad
      mii-monitor-interval: 1
```

With my **not working bonded** /etc/rc.local iptables configuration identical, except I have switched the LAN interface (enp3s0f1) for the bond interface (pigeon-lan):

```
#!/bin/bash

# /etc/rc.local

# Default policy to drop all incoming packets.
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP

# Accept incoming packets from localhost and the LAN interface.
#iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i pigeon-lan -j ACCEPT

# Accept incoming packets from the WAN if the router initiated the connection.
iptables -A INPUT -i enp3s0f0 -m conntrack \
--ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Forward LAN packets to the WAN.
iptables -A FORWARD -i pigeon-lan -o enp3s0f0 -j ACCEPT

# Forward WAN packets to the LAN if the LAN initiated the connection.
iptables -A FORWARD -i enp3s0f0 -o pigeon-lan -m conntrack \
--ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# NAT traffic going out the WAN interface.
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp3s0f0 -j MASQUERADE

# rc.local needs to exit with 0
exit 0
```

Also, I have changed the DHCP interface in /etc/default/dhcpd.conf to hit the bond as well.

As soon as this is applied (netplan/dhcp/reboot etc.) I can't hit the WAN/LAN via the switch at all, but can ping out from the box to google etc so the WAN looks ok.

**scratching my head on this one as to where to go so any help would be appreciated!!**

FYI - my ifconfig shows:

```
docker0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        inet6 fe80::42:7eff:feab:7e59  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:7e:ab:7e:59  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 72  bytes 11027 (11.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp3s0f0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.117  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::224:81ff:fe81:8d4d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:24:81:81:8d:4d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1563  bytes 521441 (521.4 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 921  bytes 137509 (137.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 39  memory 0xfe720000-fe740000  

enp3s0f1: flags=6211<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SLAVE,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether d6:a1:38:bd:13:bc  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2306  bytes 171452 (171.4 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 3  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 128  bytes 16384 (16.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 26  memory 0xfe700000-fe720000  

enp4s0f0: flags=6211<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SLAVE,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether d6:a1:38:bd:13:bc  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 245  bytes 23278 (23.2 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 3  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 133  bytes 16830 (16.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 44  memory 0xfe520000-fe540000  

enp4s0f1: flags=6211<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SLAVE,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether d6:a1:38:bd:13:bc  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 177  bytes 15554 (15.5 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 128  bytes 16384 (16.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 24  memory 0xfe500000-fe520000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 46  bytes 3032 (3.0 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 46  bytes 3032 (3.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

pigeon-lan: flags=5187<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MASTER,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.1.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.1.0.255
        inet6 fe80::d4a1:38ff:febd:13bc  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether d6:a1:38:bd:13:bc  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2728  bytes 210284 (210.2 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 6  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 389  bytes 49598 (49.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 69 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth0b52c2b: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::bc0d:62ff:fe4c:8c7b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether be:0d:62:4c:8c:7b  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 8  bytes 656 (656.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth6ab4d9d: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::ccbe:f5ff:fed8:ae7a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether ce:be:f5:d8:ae:7a  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 87  bytes 12173 (12.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about home networking and consumer-grade devices are explicitly off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [su].

Comment: apologies didnt realise. not my intention. I have solved this now so will add the answer below for other lost souls :-)

Comment: Also, at least my switch isn't consumer grade (sort of) :-)

Answer (score 1):

Solution was:

fully configure/enable LACP on the switch first with a proper LAG group etc..

(face palm)